# How can I make Nautilus automatically show hidden files?

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

I know I can just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide the hidden files, but how do I make them visible by default?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Under your Edit -> Preferences -> Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Edit** -> **Settings**. Then select "Show hidden and backup files" on the **Views** tab to permanently set this. You can read more on the [GNOME desktop guide](http://ftp.labdoo.org/download/Public/manuals-ubuntu/English/user-guide-gnome-desktop.pdf) as well.

Comment: Looks like there is no such option anymore.